# Add .html to each single field value and add new field with 'custom_permalink'

Tags: excel, csv

I have CSV file and I can view it in excel. Here is example data:

**ID**      **Product Name** 
75  dale-earnhardt-jr-adult-costume 
77  dale-earnhardt-jr-adult-costume-2
79  plastic-jeweled-crown
81  dollar-ring
83  the-wizard-of-oz-shoe-covers-child

1) I need to add '.html' at the end of product name like dollar-ring.html 
2) I want add new column with value 'custom_permalink'

Output should be like:

**ID   New Column            Product Name**
75   custom_permalink        dale-earnhardt-jr-adult-costume.html 
77   custom_permalink        dale-earnhardt-jr-adult-costume-2.html
79   custom_permalink        plastic-jeweled-crown.html
81   custom_permalink        dollar-ring.html
83   custom_permalink        the-wizard-of-oz-shoe-covers-child.html

I've 30K records and want to add this using some easy way of excel?

Comment: `&` operator performs string concatenation. Like `=A1&".html"`.

Comment: would you please add more details. I'm new to excel

Comment: Okay, I will answer this below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a trivial issue that shows no research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open/import your CSV file in Excel. Say, it is now in columns `A` and `B`.

In cell `C1` write `=A1`.

In cell `D1` write `custom_permalink`.

In cell `E1` write `=B1&".html"`.

Select cells `C1:E1` and fill the formula till the bottom of your data.

Copy and paste special columns `C:E` as values only.

Delete columns `A:B`.

Comment: Great. One thing more. I don't want to move to new file as formula. I want to move all the new fields as text? Can you help me with that to?

Comment: Just select all your columns with formulas, then copy them, then right-click the selection and choose Paste Special - Values Only.

Answer (score 1):

In cell `B2` of CSV file add the below formula.

`=CONCATENATE(A1, ".html")`

Select the range in column `B` and filldown formulas using shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.